# I can't see wordpress .php file?

Tags: php, dreamweaver, wordpress

I installed WAMP server on Windows XP - it worked. I installed **Wordpress 3.4.2** into `www.wordpress` - no problem. In Dreamweaver CS5 I created a site with `www.wordpress` as root folder, and assigned a local test server - no problem.

The, in Dreamweaver, I opened `twentyten` theme - `index.php` - and pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> to see the page in Firefox - and got:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()... - on line 16
```

This is a completely new and clear wordpress installation. **Why is the function (`get_header`) - undefined?** To check the server I copied another .php file into the same folder - <kbd>F12</kbd> - it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the <kbd>F12</kbd> in Dreamweaver , it will open the file in the browser using the windows local path file system to the file, which wont work as you should run the file on localhost.

Using <kbd>F12</kbd> file will open as `C:\\Wamp\Wordpress\index.php`.

But you should rather open it as `localhost/wordpress/`.

Also, you should be running `index.php` that is in wordpress folder and not the index file that is in themes folder.

Comment: This is address with F12: `http://localhost/wordpress 3.4.2/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/index.php`

Comment: what errors does it throw. If you see header.php as undefined, that means your index.php hasn't a call to get_header() function defined in  header.php

Comment: But it should call it, I suppose.

Comment: off course, but it is defined by default in the twenty eleven, You don't need to modify the theme . if you have set up your localhost properly there is no reason that it wont work properly. My  guess is that you haven't installed wamp/or running wordpress on localhost properly

Comment: I can see starting wordpress page when clicking on `WAMP - localhost - wordpress`, so installation is ok.

Comment: btw you should be running index.php that is in wordpress folder and not the index file that is in themes folder

Comment: `btw you should be running index.php that is in wordpress folder and not the index file that is in themes folder`. I think this is the answer. Thanks a lot, refhat.

Comment: glad I could help, check out my wordpress built site http://www.codeforbrowser.com

Answer (score 0):

You can work on your theme files directly if you were running DesktopServer Premium instead of  WAMP. It's the only web server that supports Dreamweaver's WYSIWYG when working with WordPress template files.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bCTbjoBWa8&feature&t=4m39s

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are trying to view the wrong index.php file in your WP hierarchy. The index.php in your theme's folder is not intended to load the all the functions of the WP environment.

Open the top level index.php file in the document root. (The index.php file that is in the same directory as the wp-admin, wp-content, and wp-includes folders.) That file processes everything seen in the browser (or DW live view) when accessing your site via the web url.

You can make changes to your theme by editing the theme's file located at /wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME

Once you make the changes you can view them by previewing the top-level index.php file.

***The correct index.php file you should use to view your site through DW previewing should have the following code only by default.***

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '\wp-blog-header.php' );
```